ASUS wireless keyboard powers off my laptop running debian after waking the keyboard from sleep
I got a new ASUS ROG Falchion NX Wireless keyboard and realised quickly that the keyboard shuts down my laptop whenever the keyboard is in sleep mode and I type something. The keyboard normally goes to sleep after a few minutes of inactivity, and any keypress after this point will immediately shut down my laptop.
I have two different Acer laptops (both running debian/GNOME/x11) and the same issue persists on both systems. I suspected that the keyboard was sending some signals that were probably being misinterpreted as PowerOff signals by my laptops. I am dual booting Windows on my main laptop and the issue doesn't occur on Windows.
I used xev to log the keyboard events right before the poweroff and here is the result:
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 268946, (-11,502), root:(960,540),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 269043, (-11,502), root:(960,540),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

MappingNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 269074, (-11,502), root:(960,540),
    state 0x0, keycode 124 (keysym 0x1008ff2a, XF86PowerOff), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 269074, (-11,502), root:(960,540),
    state 0x0, keycode 150 (keysym 0x1008ff2f, XF86Sleep), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 269074, (-11,502), root:(960,540),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

I pressed the left-ctrl key to wake the keyboard which can be seen in the log. The laptop immediately powered off after this, but as you can see from the log, the keyboard sent a XF86PowerOff signal as well as XF86Sleep and XF86WakeUp signals.
I then thought of disabling these signals altogether using xmodmap like so:
! ~/.Xmodmap
keycode 124 = NoSymbol
keycode 150 = NoSymbol
keycode 151 = NoSymbol

and executing xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap on startup. (I have other remappings and they seem to work just fine so I have no reason to believe this shouldn't work)
But the issue still persists and the keyboard is still sending the poweroff signals and my laptop keeps shutting down.
I found another post where someone on Ubuntu had the same issue with a different Asus Wireless keyboard and they noticed some additional keyboard devices in xinput. They disabled these devices and it seemed to fix the problem for them, so I tried the same.
xinput list output:
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse Keyboard id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION Mouse                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7DB5:01 06CB:CD41 Mouse               id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7DB5:01 06CB:CD41 Touchpad            id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION Consumer Control     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION System Control       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION                      id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ C-Media Electronics Inc.       USB PnP Sound Device   id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=24   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse Keyboard id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]

I disabled devices 16 and 18, but the issue still persists. Disabling any of the others disables my keyboard completely.

After a lot of debugging and trying to disable all kinds of devices and device settings, I found a working solution here.
Add the following lines to /etc/udev/hwdb.d/99-asus-falchion.hwdb
evdev:input:b*v0B05p193Ee0111*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_10081=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_10082=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70070=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70071=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70072=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70073=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70074=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70075=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70076=reserved
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70077=reserved

Did some more research to understand what this does.

bv0B05p193Ee0111: This is the identifier for my specific keyboard model.

v0B05 is the vendor ID for ASUS.

p193E is the product ID for the ROG FALCHION.

e0111 refers to a specific version or interface of this device from what i understand

10081 and 10082 likely correspond to system control keys like power, sleep

70070 - 70077 are probably other multimedia / system control functions


Reserved keys are ignored by the system which stops the power shenanigans.
